# Validar caracteres somente com letras e espaços (incluíndo acentos)

Tags: php

Como posso validar uma *string* e aceitar somente letras com ou sem acento e espaços? Li um pouco sobre o `ctype_alpha`, mas ele não funcionou com letras com acento, apesar de eu ter setado as configs para `pt_br`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.UTF-8', 'pt_BR.UTF-8', 'portuguese');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-alpha.php) somente verifica se os caracteres estão no intervalo `A-Za-z`. Uma opção é usar o [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) com a expressão `[\pL\s]+` para corresponder somente à [letras](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.unicode.php#regexp.reference.unicode) e espaços.

```
function validar($string) {
    return !!preg_match('|^[\pL\s]+$|u', $string);
}

var_dump(validar("joÃO Maria")); // true
var_dump(validar("joao12"));     // false
var_dump(validar("Joao"));       // true
var_dump(validar("J0ao"));       // false
var_dump(validar(" "));          // true
```

<sub>O `!!` antes do `preg_match` é usado para retornar o resultado booleano.</sub>

O modificador [`u`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) na expressão regular é para tratar a *string* como UTF-8.

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia o !!

Comment: UTF-8 é o melhor "filtro"? fiz alguns tests e as vezes não passa, quando eu removo o "u" ele fica ?? nos acentos, ´porém funciona

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Acho que é relativo. Que palavras por exemplo não passam no teste?

Comment: Tipo, na verdade tá acontecendo algo estranho, eu testo o meu form enviando as requests sem preencher o formulário, por fora, dessa forma ele dá erro, mas quando eu envio os dados do próprio form ele aceita a validação, oque será? e algo do "charset" do html?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Será que não seria mais adequado usar o `isset` antes para verificar se a variável foi definida?

Comment: Sim, ela já está devidamente "tratada", é que como meu form também é validado por jquery, é mais prático testar já enviando uma requisição pronto, mas o uso normal é pelo form mesmo.

Comment: Como posso adicionar números a esta validação?